# Responding to "write" messages

Tags: bash

Was wondering if anybody knew of a way to capture and recognize incoming `write` commands to a terminal. I've tried using `script -f` and then using `tail -f` to follow the output on a while loop but because the terminal I'm tracing does not initiate the `write` it does not get outputted. Unfortunately I do not have root permissions and cannot play with the pts or screendump, was wondering if anybody knew a method to achieve this?

Example:

```
Terminal 1 $ echo hello | write Terminal 2

Terminal 2 $
Message from Terminal 1 on pts/0 at 23:48 ...
hello
EOF

*Cause a trigger from which I can send a return message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any obvious way to do this.  Here's why...

Your shell receives its input from, and send its output to, some terminal
device:

```
   +-----------+
   |           |
   |   bash    |
   |           |
   +-----------+
         ^ |
         | |
         | v
      +----------------------+
      | some terminal device |
      +----------------------+
```

When `write` writes to the terminal, it sends data directly to the same terminal device.  It doesn't go anywhere near your shell:

```
   +-----------+     +-----------+
   |           |     |           |
   |   bash    |     |   write   |
   |           |     |           |
   +-----------+     +-----------+
         ^ |             |
         | |             |
         | v             v
      +----------------------+
      | some terminal device |
      +----------------------+
```

So, in order for you to be able to capture what is sent by `write`, you'd need some hook provided by the terminal device itself, and I don't think there is anything you can use to do this.

So how does `script` work, and why doesn't it capture the `write` output?

`script` can't hook into the terminal device either.  It really wants to interpose itself between your shell and your terminal, but there isn't a good way to do that directly.

So, it creates a *new* terminal device (a pseudo-terminal, also known as a "pty") and runs a new shell in it.  A pty consists of two sides: the "master", which is just a stream of bytes, and a "slave", which looks just like any other interactive terminal device.

The new shell attaches to the slave side, and `script` controls the master side -- which means that it can save the stream of bytes to a file, as well as forwarding them between the new shell and the original terminal:

```
   +-----------+
   |           |
   |   bash    |
   |           |
   +-----------+
         ^ |
         | |
         | v
+-----------------+  <=== slave side of pty -- presents the interface of
| pseudo-terminal |                                an interactive terminal
+-----------------+  <=== master side of pty -- just a stream of bytes
         ^ |                      
         | v     
   +-----------+
   |           |
   |  script   |
   |           |
   +-----------+
         ^ |
         | |
         | v
      +----------------------+
      | some terminal device |
      +----------------------+
```

Now you can see that a `write` to the original terminal device bypasses everything, just like it did in the simple case above:

```
   +-----------+
   |           |
   |   bash    |
   |           |
   +-----------+
         ^ |
         | |
         | v
+-----------------+  <=== slave side of pty -- presents the interface of
| pseudo-terminal |                                an interactive terminal
+-----------------+  <=== master side of pty -- just a stream of bytes
         ^ |                      
         | v     
   +-----------+     +-----------+
   |           |     |           |
   |  script   |     |   write   |
   |           |     |           |
   +-----------+     +-----------+
         ^ |             |
         | |             |
         | v             v
      +----------------------+
      | some terminal device |
      +----------------------+
```

If you write data to the slave side of the *new* terminal here, you *will* see the output show up, because it will appear in the stream of data on the master side, which `script` sees.  You can find the name of the new pty with the `tty` command from the shell inside `script`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't help with `write`, as you probably won't be able to `write` to it: your login session is associated with the original terminal, not the new one, and `write` will probably complain that you're not logged in.  But if you e.g. `echo hello >/dev/pts/NNN`, you'll see that it does show up in the `script` output.

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed explanation, I didn't realize that `script` worked through a secondary pseudo-terminal so that was interesting. I think I will try investing some time to see if get my script to detect the new pty and use it instead original for my purposes, though will have to try replicate `write`'s functionality with something that doesn't care about ID.